# PHP - How to call multiple functions of a class on top of each other

Tags: php, function, class

How to create a class that can call multiple functions?

*example:*

```
class ClassName
{
    public static function func1()
    {
    }

    public static function func2()
    {
    }

    public static function func3()
    {
    }

}

ClassName::func1()->func2()->func3();
```

*result*
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function funcX() on null

Comment: `func1()` and `func2()` need to return `ClassName` object. Even then, I'm not entirely sure the syntax at the bottom of your snippet would be exact. It would look more like `(ClassName::func1())->func2()->func3()` I believe

Comment: This won't work at all. Not with static methods. This _is_ possible with an instance object, that is called a "builder pattern" or "fiuid style".

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you cannot call static functions "piggybacked" like you can in, say, JavaScript.   You have a few options .. Call them in a list, one at a time .. Like so:

```
ClassName::func1();
ClassName::func2();
ClassName::func3();
```

Or Like

```
$foo = new ClassName;
$foo->func1();
$foo->func2();
$foo->func3();
```

Now if you want to run them all with a single call, you need to nest the functions BUT we have to rid ourselves of the `static` method ...

```
<?php

class ClassName
{
   public function func1()
   {
     echo "1 \n";
     $this->func2();
   }
   public function func2()
   {
     echo "2 \n";
     $this->func3();
   }
   public function func3()
   {
     echo "3 \n";
   }

}

$foo = new ClassName;
$foo->func1();
```

Finally, if you want to run all of your functions within a class sequentially, you can use `get_class_methods` and loop through all the functions ... IE

```
<?php

class ClassName
{
   public static function func1()
   {
      echo "1 \n";
   }
   public static function func2()
   {
      echo "2 \n";
   }
   public static function func3()
   {
      echo "3 \n";
   }
}

$functions = get_class_methods('Classname');

foreach ($functions as $function){
    ClassName::$function();
}
```

Both methods will result in:

```
1
2
3
```

If you choose to rid yourself of the static method however (as seen in our "nested function").. And you just choose public .. Then your syntax is possible using @arkascha's method of building out.

```
 public function func1(): ClassName { // From @arkascha's answer .. 

 $foo = new ClassName;
 $foo->func1()->func2()->func3();
```

The difference is [understanding public method and static method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work at all with static methods as you suggest.

This *is* possible however with an instance object, that is called "builder pattern" or "fluent style":

```
<?php
class ClassName {
    public function func1(): ClassName {
      echo "1";
      return $this;
    }

    public function func2(): ClassName {
      echo "2";
      return $this;
    }

    public function func3(): ClassName {
      echo "3";
      return $this;
    }
}

(new ClassName())->func1()->func2()->func3();
```

The output is:

> 123

Comment: "Fluent", not "fluid".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create static instance for making chain methods. Because your methods are static and cant use them like chain. After it, you need to return this function every time at the end method. Like this:

```php
class ClassName
{
    private static $self;

    public static function func1()
    {
        echo ' i am '.__METHOD__." \n";
        return self::instance();
    }

    public static function func2()
    {
        echo ' i am '.__METHOD__." \n";
        return self::instance();
    }

    public static function func3()
    {
        echo ' i am '.__METHOD__." \n";
        return self::instance();
    }

    public static function instance(){

        return self::$self ?? self::$self = new static ;   
    }

}

ClassName::func1()->func2()->func3();
```